# how to change the size of a square by reading a number from a Qlineedit

Tags: qt, resize

I made a small square in QT then put that in a loop to create 50 squares. Now I want to read a number from QlineEdit or a text field and change the size of the whole grid to that number.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

just read text property from `QLineEdit` control and use `QString::toInt()` method.
Use Assistant and Qt examples. You are asking an obvious question.

Comment: im new to the QT bit. Sorry for asking obvious questions. But can you explain that a bit.

Comment: Im actually making the "Game of life" in QTcreator and I want to be able to change the size of my whole grid of 50 squares by entering a number in a QlineEdit. So that it changes the grid size to the number entered..